# Krull Dimension and sup

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let be $A$ a ring (comutative, noetherian) and $I$ an ideal.

$$ \text{dim}(A/I)=\sup\{ \text{dim}(A/P): P\in\text{spec}(A), P\supset I\}$$

Is it true?

Comment: Yes, it is even sufficient to take the supremum over all minimal prime ideals over $I$.

Comment: I can see that  $\text{dim}(A/I)=\sup\{ \text{dim}(A_P): P\in\text{spec}(A), P\supset I\}$.
But in "Introduction to Commutative Algebra and algebraic geometry - Kunz - page 185:

 $dim(M)=\sup_{p\in\text{supp(M)}}\{ \text{dim}(R/P)\}.$

But, I just can see that

 $dim(M)=dim(R/(0:M))=\sup_{p\supset(0:M)}dim(R_P)=\sup_{p\in\text{supp}(M)}\{ \text{dim}(R_P)\}.$

Comment: For example,if $dim(A/I)=n$, then exists $\overline{P_0}\subset\overline{P_1}\subset\ldots\subset \overline{P_n}$, then $n=dim(A_{P_n})$ and $n-1=dim(P_0)$, right?

Comment: If you have any chain of prime ideals $\mathfrak p_0\subset \mathfrak p_1\subset\dots\subset \mathfrak p_d$ in $A/I$, then you will get a corresponding chain in $A/\mathfrak  p_0$, which shows that the left hand side of your equality is smaller or equal to the right hand side. The other direction is just as straightforward.

Comment: But the corresponding chain starts in $P_1$, right?

Comment: No it starts at $\mathfrak p_0$ and is of the same length as the original chain.

Comment: Thanks! $0$ is a prime ideal in $A/P_0$.